# ZSH: search history on up and down keys?

Tags: zsh, command-history, line-editor

Currently, I have the following in my .zshrc:

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```

However, this only seems to match the content of my current input before a space character occurs. For example, `sudo ls /` will match every line in my history that begins with `sudo`, while I would like it to only match lines that match my entire input. (i.e. `sudo ls /etc` would match, but not `sudo cat /var/log/messages`)

What do I need to change in order to gain the desired behavior?

Here is my entire .zshrc in case it is relevant: https://gist.github.com/919566

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [documented behavior](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control):

> `down-line-or-search`
>   Move down a line in the buffer, or if already at the bottom line, search forward in the history for a line beginning with the first word in the buffer.

There doesn't seem to be an existing widget that does exactly what you want, so you'll have to make your own. Here's how to define a widget that behaves like `up-line-or-search`, but using the beginning of the line (up to the cursor) rather than the first word as search string. Not really tested, especially not on multi-line input.

```
up-line-or-search-prefix () {
  local CURSOR_before_search=$CURSOR
  zle up-line-or-search "$LBUFFER"
  CURSOR=$CURSOR_before_search
}
zle -N up-line-or-search-prefix
```

An alternate approach is to use `history-beginning-search-backward`, but only call it if the cursor is on the first line. Untested.

```
up-line-or-history-beginning-search () {
  if [[ -n $PREBUFFER ]]; then
    zle up-line-or-history
  else
    zle history-beginning-search-backward
  fi
}
zle -N up-line-or-history-beginning-search
```

Comment: Thanks, Gilles, your first solution works pretty well, but there's one issue and I'm hoping you can help me resolve it. When I call up-line-or-search-prefix on an empty input, it gives me the last run command -- the desired behavior. However, when I run up-line-or-search-prefix again, it does an up-line-or-search on the first character of my input. Is it possible to somehow change things so that pressing the up arrow with an empty input will scroll through my history?

Comment: @rps Ah, gotcha, it was picking up the first word because the argument was missing (instead of being empty as it should have). Use my edited version.

Answer (score 56):

zsh provide this functionality by using

```
history-beginning-search-backward
history-beginning-search-forward
```

Ex.

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward
```

Find exact Key code by
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>KEY</kbd>

Ex.
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>UP</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd>
etc.

In case if you are using mac the below works on OSX catalina.

```
 bindkey "\e[5~" history-search-backward
 bindkey "\e[6~" history-search-forward
```

Comment: An alternative for keycodes that might work across different terminals can be found in zprezto \[[1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/28a20b48e652a01216a6c3dd76e6324d76c12def/modules/editor/init.zsh)].  <kbd>Up</kbd> is `$terminfo[kcuu1]`, <kbd>Down</kbd> is `$terminfo[kcud1]`.

Comment: CTRL+v is a bad choice, this use used to paste stuff.

Answer (score 16):

This [blog post from 2013](https://coderwall.com/p/jpj_6q/zsh-better-history-searching-with-arrow-keys) recommends a couple of keybinds that match all the words before the cursor.

```bsh
# Cycle through history based on characters already typed on the line
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "$key[Up]" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "$key[Down]" down-line-or-beginning-search
```

If `$key[Up]` and `$key[Down]` don't work on your machine, you could try `$terminfo[kcuu1]` and `$terminfo[kcud1]` instead.

Comment: zsh also gives these friendlier aliases (at least in the ubuntu package) in `/etc/zsh/zshrc`, such as `$key[Up]`.

Comment: If using `$terminfo` you'll need to change the terminal modes. See [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/3705d47bb3f3229234cba992320eadc97a221caf/lib/key-bindings.zsh#L5).

Comment: after a lot of searching, this worked for me on my ubuntu vps

Answer (score 2):

Have also a look at the [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) project.

It offers what you are looking for, and it can even be used as a oh-my-zsh plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97844), that I think is perfect.

For example, bindkey these functions to the "Page Up" key and "Page Down" key, then when I press "Page Up" it will search through history using what I have started typing, not just the first word.

i.e. if you type `sudo ls /etc` then `sudo ls` will bring up `sudo ls /etc` but not `sudo cat...` etc.

Below is the excerpt from my zshrc.

```bsh
## Page UP and Page Down through History
autoload -Uz history-search-end

zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end \
                history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end \
                history-search-end
bindkey "\e[5~" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "\e[6~" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```