# History-search in zsh working only for commands?

Tags: zsh, command-history, line-editor

Say I have the following entries in my command history:

```
less documents/doc1.txt
less documents/doc2.txt
less files/file1.txt
less files/file2.txt
ls
pwd
```

and that I have the following keyboard binding enabled:

```
bindkey '^P' history-search-backward
```

I have noticed that if I then type:

```
less documents
^P
```

ZLE brings

`less files/files2.txt`

as the first option, rather than:

`less documents/doc2.txt`

Why is that? Is there a way to make `history-search` fix **everything on the left of my cursor** and iterate through the history with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bindkey '^P' history-beginning-search-backward
```

You might prefer [`up-line-or-history-beginning-search`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/zsh-search-history-on-up-and-down-keys/16114#16114).