# How can I search history with text already entered at the prompt in zsh?

Tags: zsh, command-history, search

In zsh, I know that I can search history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. However, oftentimes I start to type a command directly at the prompt, but then realize I should be searching history. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, it brings up a blank history search prompt like this:

[image: history search prompt not pre-filled]

Notice how there is text at my prompt but not at the history search prompt. How do I start the history search with the text already in the prompt, so it looks like this:

[image: history search prompt pre-filled]

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use [zle's `history-search`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control) functionality:

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward
```

This binds <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> (adjust for your own escape sequences) to a history search, backwards and forwards, based upon what has already been entered at the prompt.

So, if you were to enter "vim" and hit <kbd>Up</kbd>, zsh will traverse backwards through your history for only those commands commencing with "vim".

You can additionally have the cursor placed at the end of the line once you have selected your desired command from zsh's history by using the [history-search-end](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-55/zsh/Functions/Zle/history-search-end) function (typically located in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle/`) and appending `-end` to the end of each line, like so:

```
autoload -U history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I had to remove the "-end" for both bindkey commands to make them work though. I have not edited your answer because maybe there's some situation in which those are necessary?

Comment: No problem: updated the answer with the detail you wanted clarified.

Comment: This used to work for me until late Nov, Dec. 2015 when I upgraded to latest version of oh my zsh. Any ideas? suggestion? anybody else seeing this? how to debug?

Comment: @hanielabed Oh-my-Zsh is a clusterfsck; I am not at all surprised it would break something as fundamental as history search...

Comment: @jasonwryan yiikes, thanks of educating me... darn... I am slowly absorbing this after switching to zsh and oh-my-zsh about 7 months ago :)

Comment: When I try this, it only looks at the first word on the line, up to the first space. Search ignores everything after the first space.

Comment: @EddieSullivan that is by design. You want `Ctrl-r` to search the entire string.

Comment: I copied the answer into my .zshrc and nothing special happens when pressing up. `ctrl-r` does work though. I tried calling history-search-* functions directly and just get zle widget errors `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active`

Comment: Is there a way for the cursor to jump to the end from an empty history search, but stay the same position for a partial search? This is what happens in bash currently.

Comment: This didn't work on macOS. I needed to use `bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" history-beginning-search-backward-end` using zzxyz's suggestion below.

Comment: yes! this is somewhat life-changing improvement to my zsh cli experience, with two lines added to .zshrc

Comment: @pheon That’s weird; it works for me on macOS. What does `^V` then Up shows? (`^V` by default would show the escaped sequence of any following key combination.)

Comment: This is a great tip, but it doesn't exactly answer the question. In particular, it doesn't start an incremental search with the text typed already.

Answer (score 36):

Another useful option is `history | grep`

Assign an alias, e.g.

```
alias hg='history | grep'
```

then you can type `hg whatever` to search for commands you've used, e.g.

```
$ hg chmod                                                                                                       
 1309  chmod +x rotate_files.sh 
 1385  chmod +x rotate_files_270.sh 
 1512  chmod +x testy.sh 
 1528  chmod +x act_on_2_numbers.sh 
 2142  chmod +x ~/bin/display_tmux_pane_pwd.sh
 4532  chmod +x cat_files.rb
```

I put this alias in my dot files.

Comment: This alias should probably be updated to use the zsh **full** history command `history 1` (otherwise it will only grep over the most recent 15 history items) - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846738/zsh-history-is-too-short

Answer (score 29):

If you are using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), add `history-substring-search` to the `plugins=(...)` line.

Then add

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-substring-search-up
bindkey "^[[B" history-substring-search-down
```

somewhere below the line that read `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. Save and fire up a new terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` in the current terminal.

**Note:** `^[[A` is the escape sequence for up arrow in the terminal I use (kitty) and many others. To check in your terminal of choice, type in `showkey -a` and then press they key you want to find the escape sequence for.

Comment: It is unclear what this keymapping does, the answer above explains "This binds Up and Down (adjust for your own escape sequences) to a history search, backwards and forwards, based upon what has already been entered at the prompt."

Comment: @ColinD Added a note to clarify

Comment: substring search is best, its a superset of command begins with. to implement without being an oh-my-zsh user I did `brew install zsh-history-substring-search`, checked the repo readme for instructions, I'll just go ahead and create an answer I'm really happy with the result.

Comment: +1 for getting to know `showkey`! It should be a common knowledge. How I even survived without it 10+ years including time spent in vim?

Comment: It's unclear why the `bindkey` needs to be placed below `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Comment: Noting that `history-substring-search` is built into zshell.  `zsh-history-substring-search` is a second implementation: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search

Answer (score 13):

#### Third part solutions

1 - What about using [`zsh-autosuggestions`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions)?

The thing is, for each command you type this plugin will show you some suggestions that could be accepted or not. Try it out and give us some feedback.

2 - The [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) after installed and properly configurated add an widget that changes your reversed search history (by default binded to fzf-history-widget <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>), it adds some fuzzy search on your command history. I am using it and combined with the autosuggestions works like a charm.

#### Native solution

With no plugins we can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to perform a reverse seach on the history, as soon as you start typing the matched commands will appear as suggestions.

Comment: The ctrl-r solution should be number one. It's useful and always available.

Comment: This plugin is what I was looking for!

Comment: It's very useful!

Answer (score 13):

I'd highly recommend using `"$terminfo[kcuu1]"` or `"$key[Up]"` rather than hard-coded stuff like `"^[[A"` which may or may not work on any particular system.

Check out `/etc/zsh/zshrc` for more keys.  Here's what it looks like on my system.  I think the `terminfo` keys are more likely to be defined.

```
key=(
    BackSpace  "${terminfo[kbs]}"
    Home       "${terminfo[khome]}"
    End        "${terminfo[kend]}"
    Insert     "${terminfo[kich1]}"
    Delete     "${terminfo[kdch1]}"
    Up         "${terminfo[kcuu1]}"
    Down       "${terminfo[kcud1]}"
    Left       "${terminfo[kcub1]}"
    Right      "${terminfo[kcuf1]}"
    PageUp     "${terminfo[kpp]}"
    PageDown   "${terminfo[knp]}"
)
```

Comment: Any example where Up isn’t `^[[A`? It seems to be the case for most (if not all) of my computers.

Comment: @FranklinYu - Nothing concrete anymore, I'm afraid, but..between Cygwin, WSL, ssh into remote Ubuntu machines, Oracle machines, x-windows terminals, and various MS Windows terminals (of varying quality), it has *definitely* been a significant issue for me.  The `terminfo` keys are almost always available and are definitely more reliable when they are.

Comment: Immaterial whether there are or aren't. When there are readable defines or macros to take the guesswork out, use them.

Comment: @FranklinYu `^[[A` didn't work in my tmux session but `$key[Up]` worked.

Comment: @GanQuan In tmux my `$key[Up]` is the same as `^[[A`. What escape code does your up-arrow produce? (You can tell with Ctrl-V mode.)

Comment: @FranklinYu `^[OA`

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use the script at https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search

Where you can type in any part of any previously entered command and press the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys to cycle through the matching commands.

Answer (score 6):

None of the existing answers begin an incremental search with what's been typed so far, like the question asked. This is actually possible:

```bash
_history-incremental-search-backward () {
    zle .history-incremental-search-backward -- $BUFFER
}
zle -N history-incremental-search-backward _history-incremental-search-backward

# this line is actually not necessary since this is default.
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

- we make a custom zle widget to wrap `history-incremental-search-backward` and pass the `$BUFFER` variable which contains the contents of the zsh prompt typed so far. You can then continue typing in the minibuffer to further narrow your search.

Naming the function after the widget allows us to simplify the code:

```bash
history-incremental-search-{back,for}ward() zle .$WIDGET -- $BUFFER
zle -N history-incremental-search-backward
zle -N history-incremental-search-forward
```

(here also extended to do it also for the forward search)

`$BUFFER` expands to the full contents of the editing buffer, replace with `$LBUFFER` if you only want to search based on what's left of the cursor.

### Screenshots

- start typing a command

  [image]
- realize you want to search in your history, press Ctrl-R, a minibuffer is opened and filled with the contents of the command line. As such, it first matches the command line just typed:

  [image]
- press Ctrl-R again, it matches a previous command, Tab or Ctrl-E to accept the result.

  [image]
- or continue typing to refine the search further

  [image]

To avoid the first backward search matching on the current buffer, we can empty the buffer before calling the original search widget and restore it upon failure:

```
history-incremental-search-{back,for}ward() {
  local saved_BUFFER=$BUFFER saved_CURSOR=$CURSOR error
  BUFFER=
  zle .$WIDGET -- $saved_BUFFER
  error=$?
  if (( error )) BUFFER=$saved_BUFFER CURSOR=$saved_CURSOR
  return error
}
zle -N history-incremental-search-backward
zle -N history-incremental-search-forward
```

Comment: This is God-tier answer. Should be the basis of several SO's/SE's questions' accepted answers. You're the only one I've seen point out the `$BUFFER` variable, and this is the closest thing to enabling truly `vi`-like search - both _in_ the line and then across the history!

Comment: There is at least one quirk that I'd like to one day spend some time working around, but this is by far the closest to what I've wanted without requiring me to install a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [vi-mode](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode) plugin. And then in my ~/.zshrc I have the following bindings:

```
bindkey "^P" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^N" history-beginning-search-forward
```

That enables me to use the `^P` and `^N` as normal backward and forward search if I don't enter any text, and as filtered search if I do.

Answer (score 2):

### Non-Oh-My-Zsh answer

This worked for me (on macOS) to get substring history easily accessible via up/down arrow. The key binding is up to you.

Substring search history is better than just accessing commands that start with a string. This is more like ctrl-r in most cases, those without globs or regex matching.

Starting from instructions at [zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search)

```
brew install zsh-history-substring-search

# add the following to .zshrc
source /usr/local/share/zsh-history-substring-search/zsh-history-substring-search.zsh
bindkey '^[[A' history-substring-search-up
bindkey '^[[B' history-substring-search-down
```

Now enjoying this thoroughly.

Comment: the new path in mac,  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-history-substring-search/zsh-history-substring-search.zsh

Answer (score 1):

I agree with cheflo that "substring" search is more useful. I cannot comment there so I started a new answer. I use oh-my-zsh, and add "history-substring-search" to the plugins=(...) of ~/.zshrc. Then source ~/.zshrc. Do not need to add anything more. Use "bindkey" to verify:

```
"^[OA" history-substring-search-up
"^[OB" history-substring-search-down
```

Later, you type "to" and up arrow, "history" will appear and "to" highlighted (if you used "history" command before).

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use [zaw](https://github.com/zsh-users/zaw), which completely replaces your search with a much better multi keyword super search, and fixes your problem as well - searching history is only one of the things zaw can search.

Small [intro/discussion here](http://blog.patshead.com/2013/04/more-powerful-zsh-history-search-using-zaw.html)

Comment: How is Zaw compared to [history-incremental-pattern-search-forward](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control)? Pattern searching seems to cover the use-case. For example if you want to search both `foo` and `bar` then you can search for pattern of `foo*bar`.

Comment: @FranklinYu - i'd say the other advantage zaw brings to the table is it does a nice full screen search, lets you edit and bookmark history selections, and lets you do the same with other sources, plus you can add your own sources too.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to know more about [jasonwryan'a answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97844/457327)

This is the mentioned file:

```bsh
# function history-search-end {
#
# This implements functions like history-beginning-search-{back,for}ward,
# but takes the cursor to the end of the line after moving in the
# history, like history-search-{back,for}ward.  To use them:
#   zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
#   zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
#   bindkey '...' history-beginning-search-backward-end
#   bindkey '...' history-beginning-search-forward-end

integer cursor=$CURSOR mark=$MARK

if [[ $LASTWIDGET = history-beginning-search-*-end ]]; then
  # Last widget called set $MARK.
  CURSOR=$MARK
else
  MARK=$CURSOR
fi

if zle .${WIDGET%-end}; then
  # success, go to end of line
  zle .end-of-line
else
  # failure, restore position
  CURSOR=$cursor
  MARK=$mark
  return 1
fi
# }
```

`zle -N widget [ function ]`  :  Create a user-defined widget.
When the new widget is invoked from within the editor,  the  specified **shell function** is called.
If no function name is specified, it defaults to the **same name as the widget**.
It is recommended that user-defined widgets should not have names starting with `.`.

```
# To make  history-beginning-search-{back,or}ward-end  an alias    for history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
# why `history-beginning-search-{back,or}ward-end` is chosen?
# There is widgets named `history-beginning-search-{back,or}ward`,
# so just add 'end' to them, showing their relevance.
```

I think, (not quite sure), without this line `if [[ $LASTWIDGET = history-beginning-search-*-end ]]`  in the file above file, the code

```
zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```

can be replaced by:

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-search-end
bindkey "^[[B" history-search-end
# less word to type
```

(Just to show the usage of `zle` and `bindkey`.
Now that we have that `if` line, don't use the simplified one.)

#### zsh's `bindkey` command

`bindkey -v`: select viins keymap and bind it to **main**
`bindkey -e`: select emacs keymap and bind it to **main**

`-A` : create alias (aka link)
`bindkey -A viins main`   makes `viins` an alias for `main`

Either `emacs` or `viins` is  linked to the name `main`.

If one of the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment  variables contain the string `vi` when the shell starts up,
then it will be `viins`,
otherwise it will be `emacs`.

Create a new keymap from `emacs`:

- `bindkey -N mymapname emacs`

To use "mymap":

- `bindkey -A mymapname main`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output or file content](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and the OP will need to type-copy command examples when trying to apply your solution. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Because I use oh-my-zsh, and I use the substring solution from joelostblom, James, 
I modify the .zshrc like this: (which at line 13, find the line "source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
", then modify code around it.)

```
plugins=(
  git
  history-substring-search
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

bindkey -v
bindkey "^[[A" history-substring-search-up
bindkey "^[[B" history-substring-search-down
```

Comment: `bindkey -v` will break ctrl-a, ctrl-e. Most likely all ctrl commands.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended solution for searching history with the text already entered at the prompt in zsh is to use the fzf utility. Fzf is a versatile command-line fuzzy finder that can greatly enhance your history search experience. Here's how you can set it up:

Install fzf: You can find installation instructions for fzf on its GitHub repository (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). Follow the installation steps specific to your operating system.

Configure fzf in your `~/.zshrc` file: Open the ~/.zshrc file in a text editor and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

This line ensures that fzf is sourced every time you start a new zsh session.

Save the changes and open a new terminal tab or restart your terminal for the changes to take effect.

To search history with the text already entered at the prompt, simply press Ctrl+R as before. However, this time, the fzf utility will be activated, providing an interactive search experience.

Start typing the command or text you want to search for, and fzf will filter the history based on your input in real-time.
You can use the Up and Down arrow keys to navigate through the search results.
Press Enter to execute the selected command, or press Ctrl+C to cancel the search and return to the prompt without executing any command.

By integrating fzf into your zsh configuration, you'll have a powerful and efficient way to search your command history, even when you've already entered text at the prompt.

Open a new tab and press CTRL+R

You should see the following:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).