# Context-Sensitive History

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

When I use OMZ, I have a very, very nice feature I like to call context-sensitive history. It's easier to show than describe. If I run:

```
% abc
% cba
```

And then I type `% a[up]`, without CS history I get`% cba`. With it I get `% abc`. What in OMZ causes this?

**EDIT:** I want this to give me results based on the *beginning* of the command. With the substring search suggested by @Thomas Dickey, it matches if what I typed was *anywhere* in the command.

**EDIT 2:**  @jasonwryan's answer in [How can I search history with what is already entered at the prompt in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97843/how-can-i-search-history-with-what-is-already-entered-at-the-prompt-in-zsh) is almost it; the only thing is that the cursor should be at the end of the new line rather than staying at its current location.

Comment: Without using OMZ (which is horrible on so many levels), the cursor is at the end of the line...

Comment: @jasonwryan I've ruled it down to the two lines from the linked answer. Watch this: https://asciinema.org/a/ccl89hz4oaggwbrkzmt566y68

Comment: Try disabling OMZ and using `"^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward-end` etc...

Comment: @jasonwryan https://asciinema.org/a/agvtkowpqo5la4tan97d3tcb7

Comment: And OMZ isn't even in the picture here.

Comment: See my comment to you under Thomas' answer

Comment: @jasonwryan Oh, I see, you have to define them manually. I'll test.

Comment: @jasonwryan It still doesn't work - "No such shell function `history-search-end'"

Comment: Did you load it as per the instructions? `autoload -U history-search-end` etc...

Comment: I didn't see anything about that in the instructions

Comment: That did it! Works perfectly.

Comment: I've updated my original answer, but it was clearly stated in the github repo I linked to...

Comment: That repo page has no instances of the word autoload.

Comment: That is how you load *all* Zsh functions...

Comment: I'm new to configuring zsh manually so I had no clue about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/history-substring-search), which according to the webpage is inspired by the `fish` shell (and offhand sounds like the way [vi-like-emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile-hlp.html#command-history) implements command history — there are probably several variations).

For other possibilities, see @jasonwryan's answer in *[How can I search history with what is already entered at the prompt in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97843/how-can-i-search-history-with-what-is-already-entered-at-the-prompt-in-zsh)*

Comment: I have never had that plugin enabled.

Comment: And I just tried adding the script, and it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Okay, it works but it's not what I'm looking for. Updating question.

Comment: You could have something simpler, like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97843/how-can-i-search-history-with-what-is-already-entered-at-the-prompt-in-zsh)

Comment: That's almost it! Just one other thing, with OMZ the cursor ends up at the end of the line, while this leaves it at its original position. Updating question.

Comment: @VirtualDXS you want [history-search-end](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/history-search-end)...